How to replicate eclipse's "Deploy plug-ins and fragments" property
Hello guys im working on a Swing app and trying to replicate the export property of the eclipse's "Deploy plug-ins and fragments".In other words I want to get the same jars as if i exported OSGI bundles from the eclipse ide.
I made some reaseach and i get familiar with PDE Build and other stuff.These are the approaches i found :

Ant scripts,
Maven and Tycho(I cannot use maven and tycho because of proxy)

So I decided that I can use Ant scripts but I couldn't do that much from the documents etc.
Can someone help ?

Eclipse plugins and OSGi are very different from ordinary apps and jars, tools for building them are not useful for other styles of app. Are you actually trying to build an RCP/OSGi style app?

Actually, I want to export the existing Osgi bundles in jar format like Eclipse IDE does (export -> plugin development -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments). I am not very familiar with this concept, but that is actually what I want to do.But my app itself is not a RCP/OSGi style app.

Plug-ins expect to run with the full OSGi support environment set up, so they won't work in an ordinary app.

Can't I at least build other Plug-ins and export them?

Yes, you could build an app to build and export plug-ins but this requires a lot of knowledge about OSGi and Eclipse plug-ins. This is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question. OSGi publish a gettting started guide, not sure what there is for Eclipse plug-ins.

I thought that if I could somehow trigger the build event from my own application, maybe the eclipse PDE build component could handle the rest of the process.

The whole of the PDE export code is deprecated, tycho is the only supported build system. But anyway your app would have to understand all the extra things plug-ins  require in the MANIFEST.MF and elsewhere.

I solve the issue about tycho and get ready for the build but this time i get the error while building :  Missing requirement: FirstOsgiProject 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.osgi 3.20.0' but it could not be found

You have to tell tycho about a "target platform" or a repository containing all the other plug-ins that an Eclipse plug-in requires.

I simply put central maven url to pom.xml but still the issue persists.

Maven is not an OSGi repository. Follow a proper tutorial https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Based on the tutorial i created that target-platform but still the issue is not solved.










Comments are not for debugging help. Ask a new question with all the required information in the question.

New question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/78830935/26587883
