Target-Platform dependency or error on tycho-maven build
Im trying build OSGi projects from my Java App using maven-Tycho.Im using process builder to run maven commands.My plan is to create a temporary pom.xml for OSGi project and use it with the pom.xml in my main project.
my temporary pom.xml i created on target osgi project looks like this :
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FirstOsgiProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>FirstOsgiProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.qualifier</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>
    <name>FirstOsgiProject</name>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.8</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <file>target-platform.target</file>
                    </target>
                    <!-- Optional: Set the Java version you are using -->
                    <!-- <executionEnvironment>JavaSE-17</executionEnvironment> -->
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>linux</os>
                            <ws>gtk</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                        <environment>
                            <os>macosx</os>
                            <ws>cocoa</ws>
                            <arch>x86_64</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eclipse-indigo</id>
            <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
            <layout>p2</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>

target-platform.target inside osgi project :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?>
<target name="Target Platform">
    <locations>
        <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="slicer" type="InstallableUnit">
            <unit id="org.eclipse.osgi" version="3.20.0"/>
            <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest"/>
        </location>
    </locations>
</target>

I can run maven clean with no error.But I get the error when i try to run maven install I get
Software being installed: FirstOsgiProject 1.0.0.qualifier [ERROR]   Missing requirement: FirstOsgiProject 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.osgi 3.20.0' but it could not be found: See log for details
Note : I have tried to change the repository link in the target platform but it didnt solved.

In your pom.xml in the <repositories> element, you have specified a quite old p2 repository which contains org.eclipse.osgi not higher than 3.7.2 (Eclipse Indigo has been released 2011). A target definition file is an alternative to simply specifying a p2 repository in the POM. Does the following work: in your pom.xml replace http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo with https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest and remove the <target> element?

Also note that the usual maven command for tycho is mvn clean verify. If you do use a target platform that normally lists whole features rather than a single plug-in.
